# How do I patch object imported by another python file?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Example abc.py:

```
from pack.def import Def

class Abc(object):
    def f(self):
        return Def().response()
```

Example test_abc.py

```
from unittest import mock, TestCase
from pack.abc import Abc

class TestAbc(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('pack.def.Def')
    def test_f(self, mock_def):
        responses = ['response1', 'response2', 'response3']
        mock_def.return_value.response.return_value = responses
        assert responses == Abc().f()
```

I assumed the mock def has been patched, but I'm doing something wrong, does someone know I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Patch it where it is used: `@mock.patch('pack.abc.Def')`.

Answer (score 1):

You must mock the object your are working. You are using the `Def` that belongs to **pack.def** package in **abc** module. When you write test for `Abc` class, and want to mock `Def` calls, you must mock the `Def` that is imported in **abc**, not from original module.

Use `@mock.patch('pack.abc.Def')` instead of `@mock.patch('pack.def.Def')`.